# R Points in Polygon

Tags: r, points

Was wondering if you could help me with the following. I am trying to calculate the amount of points that fall within each polygon US state. There are 52 states total. The point data and the polygon data are both in the same transformation.

I can run the function:

```
over(Transformed.States, clip.points)
```

Which returns:

```
 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
4718   NA  488 2688 4454 3762 2041   NA    5   NA 3620 
  11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21 
 412 3042 2028 3390 2755 4250 3275 2484  466 4255    1 
  22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32 
3238  744 4125 2926  927  495 3541 4640 3039  895  620 
  33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43 
4069 4671 3801 1012 4023  626 1158 4627  217   13 4055 
  44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51 
 573 3456   NA 4670 4505  903 4172 4641
```

However, I want to write this function so that each polygon is given a value based on the amount of points in the polygon that can then be plotted such as:

plot(points.in.state)

What would be the best function to go about this? So that I still have polygon data but with the new point in polygons data attached?

The end goal of this is to make a graduated symbol map for each state based on the values for points in each state.

Thanks!
Jim

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of your data sets? See this post for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: As @Phil says. Guessing without MCVE, store the result in a variable and then use it for indexing. `i <- over(Transformed.States, clip.points); plot(clip.points[i, ])`.

Comment: With `sf` you can do this and keep the association in a data frame with better idioms to boot.